# NetDNA MaxCDN api giving error

Tags: php, netdna-api

I am trying to use NetDNA to purge cached URLS from MaxCDN and not able to create the NetDNA object - gives me the following error message:

Fatal error: Class 'NetDNA' not found in purgeCacheDev.php on line 8

Any ideas where to look to resolve this error ?

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$api = new NetDNA("aaa","bbb","ccc");

// get account information
echo  $api->get('/account.json');

exit;
?>
```

Comment: Hey Ben, was able to replicate it.  Working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
php composer.phar update -o
```

within your project folder.

Also make sure your IP(s) are whitelisted: http://support.maxcdn.com/tutorials/how-to-whitelist-your-server-ip-to-use-the-api/